# display image keeping its ratio when the table row height is fixed

Tags: html, css

I am working on a web page that produces rows of data using PHP and MySQL. The rows have a fixed height of 70px. Each row displays an image and what I want to try and do is set the image to a size that fits within the row height and keeping its ratio.

Can anyone offer advice or point me to a post that may deal with this issue.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: simple ... `<img src="http://yourimage.com/image.jpg" height="70" />` ..this loads full image at 70px height and auto width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other option is to add a container for image with style set like:

```
.imageContainer {
    height: 70px;
    background-image: url(http://yourimage.com/image.png);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

the key is here

```
background-size: contain;
```

read more about background styling:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Scaling_background_images